# mostrar mensaje de warning ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ssh

Hola quisiera saber como podría hacer para que cuando intente conectarme por ssh me diera este mensaje de advertencia que me solicita borrar la clave publica del servidor de ssh (es lo que tengo entendido ¿?) dejo parte del mensaje que quiero que me de.

```
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
 Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
 ...
 ...
```

(El servidor es debian pero no importa puedo utilzar ubuntu si hace falta cambiar)

Comment: Ese mensaje te está diciendo que la identificación del host al que intentas acceder **no coincide** con la que está en nuestro archivo `.ssh/known_host`, y no tiene nada que ver con lo que dices. ¿ Que es **exactamente** lo que quieres hacer ?

Answer (score 3):

El mensaje que pones de ejemplo, es un mensaje de tu **cliente ssh** notificándote que algo ha cambiado entre los datos del servidor que has aceptado previamente como válidos y son almacenados en `~/.ssh/known_host`, y los datos del servidor de la sesión actual.

A pesar de que es un mensaje un poco alarmista, no siempre tiene que ser un ataque. En muchas ocasiones es algo normal.

El mensaje que muestra el **servidor ssh** al conectarse es conocido como motd (Message Of The Day).

En general en Ubuntu el comportamiento del motd está dirigido por los scripts de la carpeta `/etc/update-motd.d/`, por lo que [la estrategia para modificarlo](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-welcome-message-motd-on-ubuntu-18-04-server) varía un poco en función de lo que se quiera hacer.

Lo más sencillo es mantener el mensaje antiguo y añadir nuevo contenido al final del mensaje. Para ello se crea un archivo `/etc/motd` con el contenido que se quiera:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "Añadido al mensaje de bienvenida" > /etc/motd'
```